# C - Segmentation Fault when closing a file

Tags: c, fclose

I've come across a weird issue where I receive a segmentation fault when trying to close the file. Data is being written to the file correctly, could there be some sort of race condition happening between fflush and fclose?

```
//main.c

#define filename "/home/test.txt";
char fbuf[255];
sprintf(fbuf, "%s, %f, %f,%f \n", "big", 8.0,0.0,0.8);

sendFile(&fbuf, sizeof(fbuf), (void *)filename);

static void
sendFile( void *data, int size, char *pName)
{
    FILE *pFile = fopen(pName,"a");
    char *buf = NULL;
    buf = (char *)malloc(255);
    memcpy(buf, data, sizeof(char *)*size);

    if(pFile == NULL) {
        logger(LOG_INFO, "Error opening file\n");
}
    else {
        fwrite(buf, 1, strlen(buf), pFile);
        fflush(pFile);
        fclose(pFile);
    }
    free (buf);
}
```

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think it's`fclose` that is causing the segfault?

Comment: Please don't cast the result of malloc.

Comment: Why are you allocating 255 bytes for `buf`, while `size` is readily available? Couldn't it overflow it?

Comment: I removed my debug statements - the seg fault occurs when fclose(pFile) is called

Comment: @txcotrader It doesn't mean it is the *real* cause.

Comment: @EugeneSh.Worse, the later `strlen()` is not guaranteed to be terminated.  I don't even see the point of the `memcpy()`.

Comment: Ok, I think there is much to fix for now. Come back when done :)

Comment: You have passed `size` to the function and done quite strange things with it. In any case the data size is `1+sprintf(...)`, not the size of its buffer.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Why even bother with the `malloc()` and `memcpy()`?  Given the logic posted, a simple `fwrite( data, 1, strlen( data ), pFile );` does what the code posted seems to be intended to do.

Comment: Or if there were some advantage to copying the data prior to writing it, then a static array declaration (`char buf[255];`) is much better than `char *buf = malloc(255); ... free(buf);`.

Comment: I didn't realize just providing an address location to strlen would return the string length. Thanks for your response WeatherVane, your snippet solved the issue

Comment: I think you mean @AndrewHenle whose comment begins with my name.

Comment: Thank you Andrew Henle, you are smart and awesome!

Comment: You should read more about #define and preprocessor s, until then remove the semicolon.

Comment: When asking a question about a runtime problem, always post code that cleanly compiles.   The posted code is missing all the required #include statements.  Are we to guess which header files are being included in your actual code?

Comment: @AndrewHenle,  the call to `strlen` will return 3 because the first item into the buffer is 'b','i', 'g', '\0'

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is in `memcpy(buf, data, sizeof(char *)*size)`.

Shouldn't it be simply `memcpy(buf, data, size)`?

Looking at your example, `fbuf` (i.e. `data`) is 255 chars, and `buf` is 255 chars as well. But the `memcpy` is copying more than one thousand chars effectively writing garbage into the heap, with unpredictable results.

Comment: That won't make a difference.  One real problem is what happens if `size` is greater than 255 divided by the size of a `char *`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: well, it will make a difference, since `sizeof(char*)*size` is much much bigger that `size` (4 or 8 times `size`, depending on the implementation)

Comment: Yeah, but he's also using `strlen()` while not guaranteeing the copied data is terminated.  Just write the string to the file.  There are lots of issues with just the code posted.

Comment: The incorrect size parameter in `memcpy()` does not overwrite the stack but the heap and this most likely causes the FILE * data structures to be overwritten -> coredump in `fclose()`.

Comment: @schily: oops! Thanks. You are right. I will fix the answer.

Comment: this answer is not the only reason the OPs code causes a seg fault event.  Amongst other things, opening a file in the `/home` directory and calling free() when the call to fopen() fails

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version of the code that works, with embedded comments about why things are different from the posted code.

Note: On linux (and other OSs) the `/home` directory is not writeable without administrative privileges.  so the call to `fopen()` will always fail.

```
//main.c

#include <stdio.h>  // fwrite, fopen, fclose, perror
#include <stdlib.h> // exit, EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h> // strlen, sprintf, memcpy

// note: no comments at end of #define statement as the comment would be copied into the code
// note no ';' at end of #define statement
#define filename "/home/test.txt"
 // to avoid using 'magic' numbers in code
 // and this name used throughout the code
#define BUF_SIZE (255)

// prototypes
void sendFile( char *, char *); // so compiler does not make incorrect assumptions
                                // and no second parameter needed

char fbuf[BUF_SIZE] = {'\0'}; // avoid 'magic' numbers
                              // avoid placing trash into output file
                              // however, will place many NUL bytes

// main() function to make executable platform for testing
int main( void )
{
    sprintf(fbuf, "%s, %f, %f,%f \n", "big", 8.0, 0.0, 0.8);
     // changed 3rd parameter type to match actual function parameter type
    sendFile(fbuf, filename); // no '&' because in C
                              // array name degrades to address of array
    return 0;
}

void sendFile( char *data, char *pName) // use actual parameter types
{
    FILE *pFile = fopen(pName,"a");
    if(pFile == NULL)  // always check for error immediately after call to system function, not later
    { // then fopen failed
         perror( "fopen failed" );
        //logger(LOG_INFO, "Error opening file\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE); // exit, so no other code executed
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    char *buf = NULL;
    if(NULL == (buf = malloc(BUF_SIZE) ) ) // don't cast returned value
    { // then malloc failed   -- always check for error immediately after call to system function
        perror( "malloc for output buffer failed");
        //logger(LOG_INFO, "malloc for BUF_SIZE failed");
        fclose( pFile); // cleanup
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  // exit, so no other code executed
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    memcpy(buf, data, BUF_SIZE); // using original 3rd parameter would move 4 times as many bytes,
                             // I.E. past the end of the source buffer and past the end of the destination buffer
                             // resulting in undefined behaviour, leading to a seg fault event
                             // this memcpy() and the destination buffer
                             // are unneeded as first passed in parameter
                             // contains ptr to the source buffer
                             // which can be used in the call to fwrite()

    fwrite(buf, BUF_SIZE, 1, pFile); // buf will have NUL byte immediately after 'big' so strlen() would return 3
                                     // and the syntax for fwrite is source buffer, size of one item, number of items, FILE*
                                     // and this parameter order is best
                                     // because, if error checking,
                                     // can just compare returned value to 1
    fflush(pFile);  // not actually needed as the fclose() performs a flush
    fclose(pFile);

    free (buf);     // original code did this even if malloc had failed
                    // and even if the fopen had failed
                    // which would have corrupted the 'heap' leading to a seg fault event
}
```